# Set option of the Select box according to JSON result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I actually have some questions but I will start with the main one. I want to set the value of Select box on the basis of JSON.

Here's the HTML in question,

```
<label class="lbl">Office: </label>
    <select tab-index="6" class="required" name="office" class="off">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="U">London</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="R">Delhi</option>
        <option value="W">Lisbon</option>
    </select>
```

JSON sends it like this, I can't show the full JSON since it's too big, but I will show a part, `Location: "U"`.

Here's the JS part:

```
if (data.Office === "R") {
    $('select option[value="Delhi"]').prop('selected', true);
}
if (data.Office === "U") {
    console.log('here');
    $('.off option[value="London"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
if (data.Office === "W") {
    $('select option[value="Lisbon"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

But it's not working? Can any one point out why?

Moreover, I have a list of managers say and I am also getting that in JSON. So I am doing this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Managers.length; i++) {
    find_input = $('input[name="project_manager[]"').length;
    if (find_input != data.Managers.length) {
        $('<input type="text" name="project_manager[]" class="" value="" />').appendTo('#managers');
    }
    console.log(data.Managers[i].Manager);
    $('input[name="project_manager[]"').each(function() {
        $(this).val(data.Managers[i].Manager);
    });
}
```

No of textboxes depend on the number of managers, but it only sets the value of last item from the array of managers in text boxes that are appended. Why?

Moreover I am not able to set value of `textarea` in Firefox like this:

```
$('textarea#some_id').val(data.Description);
```

It works in Chrome though.

Comment: Are you missing a `<` bracket on one of your options of is that just a typo here?

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing `attr` and `prop` calls. You should be using `prop` for the `selected` flag

Comment: It works well on Firefox, the reason must be something else. For the first part of your question, what do you mean by not working? Can you give JS Fiddle?

Comment: Yeah the missing '<'  is just a typo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add the character "<" in the beginning of the 3rd option of the select box:

`<option selected="selected" value="R">Delhi</option>`

Now, in the JS code, your problem is that you're using the wrong value. Instead of:

`$('select option[value="Lisbon"]').prop('selected', true);`

You must use:

`$('select option[value="W"]').prop('selected', true);`

I hope it help.

Comment: I will surely try this, now that should work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selectors should be of the form:

```
$('select option[value="R"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Note the value is the same as the value in the HTML, not the displayed string (i.e. 'R' instead of 'Delhi').

Also, you should be using `prop()` consistently for selected flag, as described [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/) by John Resig.